# SOLVE: AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_independent'

Tags: python, plot, 3d, sympy

I am quite new to python and I have been trying to plot this in a few different ways. If I try using np.vectorize, it crashes.

so i wrote this code, which is giving me the error in the title:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solve
import sympy


fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#we define a function where we use sympy.solvers.solve and return both values of z
def surfacez(x, y):
    z = Symbol('z')
    surface = solve(x + 2 * y + z + math.e ** (2 * z), z)
    return surface


Z = surfacez(X,Y)


#we plot for both values of z
surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, antialiased=False, color='b')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.title('Quadratic surface')
```

with full traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\natty\Desktop\LU\MATB21\crash.py", line 39, in <module>
    Z = surfacez(X,Y)

  File "C:\Users\natty\Desktop\LU\MATB21\crash.py", line 32, in surfacez
    surface = solve(x + 2 * y + z + math.e ** (2 * z), z)

  File "C:\Users\natty\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1096, in solve
    solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)

  File "C:\Users\natty\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1730, in _solve_system
    i, d = _invert(g, *symbols)

  File "C:\Users\natty\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 3109, in _invert
    indep, dep = lhs.as_independent(*symbols)

AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_independent'
```

i do not know what this error means, could you suggest a way to fix or the origin of this error?

Comment: Looks like the expression you give `sympy.solve`, `x + 2 * y + z + math.e ** (2 * z)`, is not a valid one.  It's created from 2d `numpy` arrays.  Are you sure `sympy` can handle that.  Read, and if necessary reread, the `sympy` docs.  Do not naively mix `sympy` and `numpy`.   Either use a pure `sympy` code, or a pure `numpy/scipy`.code.  Maybe when you are proficient in both you can combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [66]: z
Out[66]: z
In [67]: X,Y=np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[1,2])
In [68]: X
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [69]: Y
Out[69]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
In [71]: expr = X +2 * Y + z + E  ** (2*z)
In [72]: expr
Out[72]: 
array([[z + exp(2*z) + 3, z + exp(2*z) + 4, z + exp(2*z) + 5],
       [z + exp(2*z) + 5, z + exp(2*z) + 6, z + exp(2*z) + 7]],
      dtype=object)
```

Looks like `solve` has converted this numpy array to sympy Array:

```
In [74]: Array(expr)
Out[74]: 
⎡     2⋅z           2⋅z           2⋅z    ⎤
⎢z + ℯ    + 3  z + ℯ    + 4  z + ℯ    + 5⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢     2⋅z           2⋅z           2⋅z    ⎥
⎣z + ℯ    + 5  z + ℯ    + 6  z + ℯ    + 7⎦
In [75]: type(_)
Out[75]: sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray
```

I haven't explored `solve` that much, but evidently this isn't one of the kinds of systems of expressions that it can handle.

For scalar values

```
In [80]: X,Y=1,2
In [83]: expr = X +2 * Y + z + E  ** (2*z)
In [84]: expr
Out[84]: 
     2⋅z    
z + ℯ    + 5
In [85]: solve(expr,z)
Out[85]: 
⎡      ⎛   -10⎞⎤
⎢     W⎝2⋅ℯ   ⎠⎥
⎢-5 - ─────────⎥
⎣         2    ⎦
```

and with symbols `x` and `y`:

```
In [86]: expr = x +2 * y + z + E  ** (2*z)
In [87]: expr
Out[87]: 
               2⋅z
x + 2⋅y + z + ℯ   
In [88]: solve(expr,z)
Out[88]: 
⎡            ⎛   -2⋅x - 4⋅y⎞⎤
⎢           W⎝2⋅ℯ          ⎠⎥
⎢-x - 2⋅y - ────────────────⎥
⎣                  2        ⎦
In [89]: sol=_[0]
In [90]: sol.subs({x:1, y:2})
Out[90]: 
      ⎛   -10⎞
     W⎝2⋅ℯ   ⎠
-5 - ─────────
         2
```

We could try creating a python function from that:

```
In [91]: f = lambdify((x,y),sol)
In [92]: help(f)

Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x, y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, y)
    
    Expression:
    
    -x - 2*y - LambertW(2*exp(-2*x - 4*y))/2
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return (-x - 2*y - 1/2*lambertw(2*exp(-2*x - 4*y)))
```

I'm not sure about that `LambertW`.  Obviously there's nothing in the stock python/numpy like that.  `scipy` maybe.

OK, scipy does have it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html

```
In [95]: from scipy.special import lambertw as lambertW
In [96]: f(1,2)
Out[96]: (-5.000045395808017+0j)
```

Compare that with `sympy's` own numeric solution:

```
In [97]: sol.subs({x:1, y:2})
Out[97]: 
      ⎛   -10⎞
     W⎝2⋅ℯ   ⎠
-5 - ─────────
         2    
In [98]: N(sol.subs({x:1, y:2}))
Out[98]: -5.00004539580802
```

and with array arguments, the lambdified function:

```
In [99]: X,Y=np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[1,2])
In [100]: f(X,Y)
Out[100]: 
array([[-3.00246655+0.j, -4.00033524+0.j, -5.0000454 +0.j],
       [-5.0000454 +0.j, -6.00000614+0.j, -7.00000083+0.j]])
```

`sympy.lambdify` is one of the best tools for using `sympy` expressions in `numpy` functions.  It can't handle all cases, since the translation is largely lexical, without deep understanding of `numpy`.  There have been SO about such cases.